# Removing columns with 0 in R in a table

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, multiple-columns

I have a dataframe in R. From this dataframe I have extracted one column to work with. This column has a variable and a frequency.
E.g:

```
      Var1  Freq
1  1100  1697
2  1200  2551
3  1300  4064
4  1400   978
5  2100  1529
6  2200  2006
7  2300  2900
8  2400  1336
9  3100  1808
10 3200  6075
```

I have then sorted this so that the highest 5 frequencies are shown at the top and the remaining are grouped under 'other' and turned this into a dataframe e.g:

```
   Var1  Freq
1  6000 23844
2  4800 23216
3  3300  8821
4  3200  6075
5  3400  4595
6 other 28737
```

As my aim is to get this data  into a pie chart to show proportions I then converted the dataframe into a table using

```
#convert dataframe into table
mytableSC <- table(expandRows(sectorcode_otherdf, "Freq"))
```

mytableSC gives me...

```
 1100  1200  1300  1400  2100  2200  2300  2400  3100  3200  3250  3300  3350  3400  3500  4600  4700  4800  4900  6000 
    0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0  6075     0  8821     0  4595     0     0     0 23216     0 23844 
 7000 other 
    0 28737
```

I want to remove the columns with 0 in and I have to do this with many other columns from the initial dataframe so I would like this to be automated. I have tried various things but none seem to work
For example: `newtable <- mytableSC[,mytableSC[1,] != 0]`
returns an error code: Error in `[.default`(mytableSC, 1, ) : incorrect number of dimensions

I can use `newtable <- mytableSC[-c(1:9, 11, 13, 15:17, 19, 21)]`
and this actually does work but this would be a long and tedious process as other columns have a lot more variables and it would take me a lot longer to count which columns had 0 in.
I have also tried other things but I am not sure code for matrices or dataframes would work on this particular problem.
Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `newtable <- mytableSC[mytableSC!=0]`

Comment: Such a simple solution! This works wonderfully, thanks a lot!

Comment: Yes, `mytableSC` is a named vector (onedimensional object). My solution is only a generalisation of your `mytableSC[-c(1:9, 11, 13, 15:17, 19, 21)]`. The code, which gave the error, has too much commas (for indexing more than one dimension).

Comment: You could use `droplevels` on the factor (or just `as.character`) to get rid of non-occurring levels. If you really need a named vector, you could just use `setNames` instead of expanding and aggregating again.

Comment: Why do you need to use `table` to create a pie chart? Can't you just do`pie(mydf$Freq, labels = mydf$Var1)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be going about this a very roundabout way. To create a pie chart (not going to make a judgement call on that) you can directly use the values in your sorted and aggregated `data.frame`. Something like the following should do it:

```
pie(mydf$Freq, labels = mydf$Var1)
```

If you want the intermediate named vector, you can generate it like this:

```
setNames(mydf$Freq, mydf$Var1)
##  6000  4800  3300  3200  3400 other 
## 23844 23216  8821  6075  4595 28737
```

---

If this is really about removing zeroes from a table and not about getting a pie chart from what you have, then there are a couple of options to look at. Here's some reproducible sample data:

```
set.seed(1)
myvec <- factor(sample(letters[sample(26, 5)], 100, TRUE), letters)
mytab <- table(myvec)

mytab
## myvec
##  a  b  c  d  e  f  g  h  i  j  k  l  m  n  o  p  q  r  s  t  u  v  w  x  y  z 
##  0  0  0  0 17  0 13  0  0 24  0  0  0 18  0  0  0  0  0  0 28  0  0  0  0  0 

mytab[mytab > 0]           # alternative of @jogo
## myvec
##  e  g  j  n  u 
## 17 13 24 18 28 

mytab[mytab != 0]          # @jogo
## myvec
##  e  g  j  n  u 
## 17 13 24 18 28 

table(droplevels(myvec))   # @alistaire
## 
##  e  g  j  n  u 
## 17 13 24 18 28
```

Comment: I am only using pie charts because I was asked to (I admit they aren't as effective as other charts). Because I had to group some of the variables into an 'other' category that's what caused me problems, as opposed to creating a pie chart directly from the dataframe. Thanks for your comments/help/examples, it was very useful.